# I would like to show the same class tiles when i click on them in java

Tags: java, swing

Im not that known with java. When i start my jframe (memory card game), And i click on two the same tiles only the first one shows. Example: when i click on the 
new OrangeTile and then on the other    new OrangeTile only the first one stays on the tile.showface

```
package control;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import Tiles.*;


public class Control extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static Control CurrentWindow = null;

private final String title ="Remembory";

private Tile SelectedTile = null;
private int points = 0;

public Control() {

    setSize(250,260);
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setUpGame();

    setVisible(true);

}

private void setUpGame()
{
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(new OrangeTile());
    getContentPane().add(new OrangeTile());
    getContentPane().add(new YellowTile());
    getContentPane().add(new YellowTile());
    getContentPane().add(new GreenTile());
    getContentPane().add(new GreenTile());
    getContentPane().add(new RedTile());
    getContentPane().add(new RedTile());
    getContentPane().add(new BlueTile());
    getContentPane().add(new BlueTile());
    getContentPane().add(new GrayTile());
    getContentPane().add(new GrayTile());
    getContentPane().add(new WhiteTile());
    getContentPane().add(new WhiteTile());
    getContentPane().add(new TurqTile());
    getContentPane().add(new TurqTile());

}

private void AddPoint() {
    points++;
    System.out.println(" + " + points + "Points");

}

public void TileClicked (Tile tile){
    if (SelectedTile == null) {
        tile.showFace();
        SelectedTile = tile;
        return;
    }
    if (SelectedTile == tile) {
            tile.hideFace();
            SelectedTile = null;
            return;
    }
    if (points == 7){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (SelectedTile.getFaceColor() == tile.getFaceColor()) {
        AddPoint();
        getContentPane().remove(SelectedTile);
        getContentPane().remove(tile);
        SelectedTile = null;
        return;
    }
    SelectedTile.hideFace();
    SelectedTile = null;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    CurrentWindow = new Control();
}
```

}

```
package Tiles;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Tile extends JLabel implements MouseListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Color faceColor = Color.BLACK;
private final static Dimension size = new Dimension(50,50);

public Tile()
{
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setOpaque(true);
    setBackground(new Color(213,86,31));
    addMouseListener(this);
}



public void showFace()
{
    setBackground(faceColor);
}
public void hideFace()
{
    setBackground(new Color(213,86,31));

}

protected void setFaceColor(Color c)
{
    this.faceColor = c;
}

public Color getFaceColor()
{
    return this.faceColor;

}


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    control.Control.CurrentWindow.TileClicked(this);
}


public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}


public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

}


public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {


}
```

}

Comment: Again.. so you need to narrow down th ecode scope. This is too much code. try to narrow

Comment: it is not easy to understand the based in your explanation, but you are comparing the 'SelectedTile == tile' in a wrong way.. use: 'SelectedTile.equals(tile)' and make sure to implement the equals method in the tile

Answer (score 1):

In public void TileClicked (Tile tile) you can only use tileShowface once when SelectedTile == null
The fist time you enter this method you set the SelectedTile = tile so the next time you enter this method the statement
if (SelectedTile == null) is false so you can't call the tileShowface method twice
unless you set the SelectedTile back to null

Maybe you should use a different counter to know if this is the first tile the player clicks or the second. And after 2 clicks on different tiles set this counter back to zero